# DropDownList display only Name of Models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, html.dropdownlistfor

i have to create a `DropDownList` which value filled from database through WCF REST. as this far the json got the data, but when i use it and put it on `DropDownList` HTML Helper, the `SelectList` always shown only Name of the Model.

[Screenshot Result Name of model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGbzO.png)

but when i put the model on `@HTML.DisplayFor` , the data shown like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jiGT.png)

**View**

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.GetClassID, "Select")
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GetSchedule.ClassIDS, new SelectList(Model.GetClassID, "ClassID"), new { @class = "select2" })
```

i'm used Select 2 but pretty sure this isn't class mistake, coz nothing changed when i delete the class

**Retrieve JSON from WCF**

```
public List<ClassIDOnly> GetSingleClassID()
{
    var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(SU.URLService + "ViewSingleClassID");
    JObject rss = JObject.Parse(json);
    JArray items = (JArray)rss["GetSingleClassIDResult"];
    var myReturn = new List<ClassIDOnly>();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        myReturn.Add(new ClassIDOnly
        {
            ClassID = Convert.ToInt32(rss["GetSingleClassIDResult"][i]["ClassID"]),
        });
        Console.WriteLine(myReturn);
    }
    return myReturn;
}
```

it works properly.

**Model**

```
public class MixSchedule
{
    public Schedule GetSchedule { get; set; }
    public List<ClassIDOnly> GetClassID { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
ClassModel cm = new ClassModel();
var viewm = new MixSchedule
{
    GetClassID = cm.GetSingleClassID()
};
return View (viewm);
```

i was try many way including use ViewBag but the result are same. is there something wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So I think you need to review a few things:

1. In your model, GetClassID should not reflect a list of elements but the element selected by the user:
   I could look like this:

   `public class MixSchedule { public string ClassID { get; set; } }`
2. If you don't tell `SelectList` which is the dataTextField it will call to `ToString` method. That's why you're not getting the right text. So it should look something like this:

   `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ClassID, new SelectList(Model.GetClassID(), "ClassID", "ClassID"), new { @class = "select2" })`

Comment: Hmm i see. Thank you let me review it later

Comment: i've tried it but the result turn out to be like this https://ibb.co/nsiYdF